# Вывод древовидной структуры в шаблоне jinja2

Tags: python, django, python-2.x, jinja2

Имеется список словарей вида:

```
[
 {'comment_id': 9, 'level': 1, 'path': [9]},
     {'comment_id': 11, 'level': 2, 'path': [9, 11]},
 {'comment_id': 12, 'level': 1, 'path': [12]},
     {'comment_id': 13, 'level': 2, 'path': [12, 13]},
     {'comment_id': 14, 'level': 2, 'path': [12, 14]},
         {'comment_id': 15, 'level': 3, 'path': [12, 14, 15]},
             {'comment_id': 16, 'level': 4, 'path': [12, 14, 15, 16]}
]
```

`comment_id` - уникальный идентификатор комментария, `level` - уровень вложенности, `path` - список-путь к родителю, где каждый элемент является идентификатором `comment_id`.

Вывод на стринце должен быть такой:

```
comment9
    comment11
comment12
    comment13
    comment14
        comment15
            comment16
```

Возможно ли повторить подобную вложенность в шаблоне `jinja2` располагая имеющимися данными?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How to generate an html directory list using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10961378/4279)

Comment: Когда я реализовывал такое у себя, я просто заводил питоновую функцию, переводящую такой список комментов в подходящее для jinja2 дерево

Answer (score 4):

Пример из документации http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/

```
<ul class="sitemap">
{%- for item in sitemap recursive %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.href|e }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {%- if item.children -%}
        <ul class="submenu">{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
    {%- endif %}</li>
{%- endfor %}
</ul>
```